# fortran read and write from file(reading from .msh and writing to dat)

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to read a .msh file and want to generate .dat file in rearranged manner (node number, x1 ,y1 , z1, x2, y2, z2)

```
$MeshFormatv
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$PhysicalNames
4
1 1 "inlet"
1 2 "top"
1 3 "exit"
1 4 "bottom"
$EndPhysicalNames
$Nodes
45
1 -2 -2 0
2 2 -2 0
3 2 2 0
4 -2 2 0
5 -1.666666666666667 -2 0
6 -1.333333333333333 -2 0
7 -1 -2 0
8 -0.6666666666666665 -2 0
9 -0.3333333333333335 -2 0
10 0 -2 0
11 0.3333333333333335 -2 0
12 0.666666666666667 -2 0
13 1 -2 0
14 1.333333333333333 -2 0
15 1.666666666666667 -2 0
16 2 -1.666666666666667 0
17 2 -1.333333333333333 0
18 2 -1 0
19 2 -0.6666666666666665 0
20 2 -0.3333333333333335 0
21 2 0 0
22 2 0.3333333333333335 0
23 2 0.666666666666667 0
24 2 1 0
25 2 1.333333333333333 0
26 2 1.666666666666667 0
27 1.666666666666667 2 0
28 1.333333333333333 2 0
29 1 2 0
30 0.6666666666666665 2 0
31 0.3333333333333335 2 0
32 0 2 0
33 -0.3333333333333335 2 0
34 -0.666666666666667 2 0
35 -1 2 0
36 -1.333333333333333 2 0
37 -1.666666666666667 2 0
38 -2 1.555555555555556 0
39 -2 1.111111111111111 0
40 -2 0.6666666666666667 0
41 -2 0.2222222222222223 0
42 -2 -0.2222222222222223 0
43 -2 -0.6666666666666665 0
44 -2 -1.111111111111111 0
45 -2 -1.555555555555555 0
$EndNodes
$Elements
45
1 1 2 4 1 1 5
2 1 2 4 1 5 6
3 1 2 4 1 6 7
4 1 2 4 1 7 8
5 1 2 4 1 8 9
6 1 2 4 1 9 10
7 1 2 4 1 10 11
8 1 2 4 1 11 12
9 1 2 4 1 12 13
10 1 2 4 1 13 14
11 1 2 4 1 14 15
12 1 2 4 1 15 2
13 1 2 3 2 2 16
14 1 2 3 2 16 17
15 1 2 3 2 17 18
16 1 2 3 2 18 19
17 1 2 3 2 19 20
18 1 2 3 2 20 21
19 1 2 3 2 21 22
20 1 2 3 2 22 23
21 1 2 3 2 23 24
22 1 2 3 2 24 25
23 1 2 3 2 25 26
24 1 2 3 2 26 3
25 1 2 2 3 3 27
26 1 2 2 3 27 28
27 1 2 2 3 28 29
28 1 2 2 3 29 30
29 1 2 2 3 30 31
30 1 2 2 3 31 32
31 1 2 2 3 32 33
32 1 2 2 3 33 34
33 1 2 2 3 34 35
34 1 2 2 3 35 36
35 1 2 2 3 36 37
36 1 2 2 3 37 4
37 1 2 1 4 4 38
38 1 2 1 4 38 39
39 1 2 1 4 39 40
40 1 2 1 4 40 41
41 1 2 1 4 41 42
42 1 2 1 4 42 43
43 1 2 1 4 43 44
44 1 2 1 4 44 45
45 1 2 1 4 45 1
$EndElements
```

I have tried with allocatable, I want to skip the lines till character '$Nodes' appear and and one more line then read it in a array and then skip the three lines of character. Read the next in another array and then rearrange the no as mentioned above.

```
program coordinates
implicit none

INTEGER:: ierror, nodeno, elementno, i, j, k , t, p, l=0, n
CHARACTER:: command

real::data(2,100)

!CHARACTER (len=5)::N!odes
!CHARACTER (len=8)::EndN!odes
!CHARACTER (len=8)::E!lements
!CHARACTER (len=11)::EndE!lements
!CHARACTER :: No*5, EndN*8, E*8, EndE*11

! CHARACTER*5 :: Nod
! CHARACTER*8 :: Ele


! real, allocatable, dimension(:,4)::node
! real, allocatable, dimension(:,7)::element

! real, allocatable, dimension(:)::n,x,y,z,a,b,c,d,g,h

!call system(l='grep -n '$Nodes' /home/user/Nitesh/Fortran/rect.msh|tail -LineNumberToStartWith|grep regEX')
! 'l = 'grep -n '$Nodes' /home/user/Nitesh/Fortran/rect.msh

command = 'grep -n $Nodes /home/user/Nitesh/Fortran/rect.msh|cut -f1 -d:'
! call system('command')

call system('grep -n '$Nodes' /home/user/Nitesh/Fortran/rect.msh|cut -f1 -d:')


! call system('l')



! print*, "enter the no. of nodes"
! read*,t
! print*, "enter the no. of elements"
! read*,p



! print*, "enter the line no. nodes data(array) starting from"
! read*,l


!allocate(node(t),element(j))


print*, "opening file"


! allocate(n(t),x(t),y(t),z(t),a(t),b(t),c(t),d(t),g(t),h(t))


OPEN (FILE='/home/user/Nitesh/Fortran/my.dat',UNIT=8, STATUS='OLD', ACTION='READ', &
IOSTAT=ierror)


 if(ierror/=0)then 
      print*,"File rect.msh cannot be open" 
      stop
  end if


  do i=1,n
      read(8,'(/)')
    end do


 do i=1,t+l
     read(8,*) data(:,i)
     !read(8,*) j,k
  end do

! 8 format('',F10.6,F10.6,F10.6,F10.6)


! if(Nod == 'Nodes') then
! read*,(n(i),x(i),y(i),z(i),i=1,t)
! end if


! if(Ele == 'Elements') then
! read*,(n(j),a(j),b(j),c(j),d(j),g(j),h(j),k=1,p)
! end if


! OPEN (UNIT=10, FILE='/home/Nitesh/rect_new.msh', STATUS='NEW', ACTION='WRITE', &
! IOSTAT=ierror)
! write(*,10)
! 10 format (' ',n())
! CLOSE (UNIT=10)


CLOSE (UNIT=8)
print*, "file read"
! do i=1,n
!  n(t)=g(j)
!  x(t),y(t),z(t)
open(file='/home/user/Nitesh/Fortran/rect.dat', unit=24, status='replace', action='write', &
IOSTAT=ierror)

if(ierror/=0)then 
      print*,"File rect.msh cannot be open" 
      stop
  end if

print*,"writing data"
   do i=1,l+t
      write(24,*) data(:,i)
   end do
print*,"data written"
! OPEN (UNIT=10, FILE='rect_new.msh', STATUS='NEW', ACTION='WRITE', &
! IOSTAT=ierror)
! write(*,10)
! 10 format (' ','The coordinates of elements')
! CLOSE (UNIT=10)
end program coordinates
```

Comment: Please remove all unnecessary lines from your code, now it is hard to read. Where do you write my.dat and what is its contents?

Comment: Don't you need an > pointing into where grep should drop it to the file? Is the  file actually there?

Comment: see my comment from Jan 17.